# Text with custom font and bold style

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-fonts

I am developing an application. I am using custom font. ".ttf" file to customize font of text view. I used the code as:

```
Typeface tfArchitectsDaughter = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(tfArchitectsDaughter);
```

**Now the need is:** I want to make the text customize as I done above as well as the style as **BOLD** in .java file.

How to do this please suggest. And what other styles or customization can be done on font please suggest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a SpannableString.
Also have a look at this tutorial.http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177.

```
String tempString="Copyright";
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
text.setText(spanString);
```

You can also use different color for text's in textview.

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");  
// make "Lorem" (characters 0 to 5) red  
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);  
textView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring. The link gives you more example of styling using spannable string.

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve it with

```
textview.setTypeface(tfArchitectsDaughter, Typeface.BOLD);
```

**Note:** For sure you can use also `ITALIC` and `BOLD_ITALIC`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code to set your text as bold

create a seperate file as style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="boldText">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="normalText">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#C0C0C0</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And in your java file if you want the text to be bold after can action means

```
Typeface tfArchitectsDaughter = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(tfArchitectsDaughter);

myTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
```

Comment: Nice and appropriate answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the code for making text bold as :

```
TextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your text bold as :

```
TextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
```