# How to set custom font for word in a TextView text

Tags: android, textview, custom-font, spannablestring

I want to set custom font for a word which is appears any where in a string.

Ex : Hai **@abc** how are you ?  , Hello my dear friend where you **@abc**

In the above examples, i have to apply custom font for "abc".  I tried with Spannable class, but i am unable to get it.

```
final TextView txtComments = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_comments);  
SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder(alcomments.get(i));
SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", tf), 0, SS.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
txtComments.setText(SS);
```

But it is affecting the entire string. Please guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i misunderstood your question.

Comment: You can use spannable string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408225/text-with-custom-font-and-bold-style and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview/16335416#16335416

Comment: Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612316/how-set-spannable-object-font-with-custom-font)

Answer (score 1):

you can manage this using html or set custom font style in textview.

1) if this scenario is in rare case then go with set html text like this,

```
TextView txtComments = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_comments); 
txtComments.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hi<font color=""#FF0000"">abc</font>"));
```

else set custom font like this.

2)

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
txtyour.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
First Part Not Bold   BOLD  rest not bold

String normalBefore= "First Part Not Bold ";
String normalBOLD=  "BOLD ";
String normalAfter= "rest not bold";
String finalString= normalBefore+normalBOLD+normalAfter;
Spannable sb = new SpannableString( finalString );
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), finalString.indexOf(normalBOLD), normalBOLD.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //bold
sb.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(intSize), finalString.indexOf(normalBOLD), normalBOLD.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//resize size
```

to show this in TextView

```
textview.setText(sb);
```

Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828482/2480911

If you want to apply custom text then

//Give Font path here. In my case i put font in asset folder.

```
String fontPath = "bankgthd.ttf";

    // text view label


final TextView txtComments = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_comments);  

    // Loading Font Face


Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font


txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Just change the content while copy and pasting, what do you mean by `You can do this either as @Rajesh suggested or by this.` no need of this line here.

Comment: @InnocentKiller . I was editing my answer and by mistake pressed submit. :) Hope this will work for this question. It works in my code.